# Design a SMTP server for High Volume Outbound Email

Tags: smtp, performance

We are developing an application which will require to send around 30 outbound emails per second. We have a server running SMTP but this machine in cloud hosted and I do not have any idea what kind of configuration will I require to support such a load. I do not even know if this load is considered to be average or high. Do i need to do anything special for such a load. Do i need a dedicated quad core server for this kind of load or lets say just 1/10th CPU of a quad core server is good enough

Answer (score 0):

Hm

what for?

- 30 emails per second is nothing. I wrote a server like 10 years ago hitting about 5000 per second (to one other server taking it down in the process - custoemr wanted as fast as possible, i delivered).
- Get any little MTA and jst use it. No sense in writing something yourself for that low volume.
- Unless you hit the server with a lot of stuff at once (loading it for transfer), a small VPS should be ok.

Seriously, 30 emails per second is what I sometimes send from my dialup account. THis is not even a visible volume for a decent message transfer agent. It is definitely NOT "high volume".

Comment: Great Thanks, I am so relieved

Answer (score 0):

Going to echo TomTom on this one and say just to get one of the many services out there that will help you do this. It's probably far easier to utilize one of their services and not have to worry about reputation monitoring and all the fun stuff of SMTP servers than to create your own solution.

Let me know if you need help finding these services.

(**Full Disclosure:** I work for [PostageApp.com](http://www.postageapp.com), and we're rolling out a hosted SMTP service soon!)